UWP app connecting to db in debug mode while firing an exception after being compiled in release mode
I'm facing an issue where one line of code is working in debug mode but not in release mode. I have an UWP app which connects to a sqlite db in the localState folder, the line of code that does that is the one that follows
Connection = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path}\\{DB_NAME}");

I'm using the package System.Data.SQLite from SQLite Development Team, installed via NuGet, and imported as follows
using SqliteConnection = System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection;

The logic is: i have a db somewhere in the pc, i have to copy the db to the localState folder (which already works), and i need to open it to start working with the data, super basic stuff. Here comes the issue: while in debug everything is working as expected, publishing the project in release mode results in the following exception on the first shared line of code
2024-08-09 11:37:58 - Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1 -    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String, String) + 0x50
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String, Boolean) + 0x34b
   at Prime.Db.Database.<Inizializza>d__12.MoveNext() + 0x16f
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() + 0x21
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task) + 0x70
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task) + 0x38
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task) + 0x17
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() + 0xb
   at Prime.SplashScreenPage.<CaricamentoIniziale>d__8.MoveNext() + 0x3e2a
 - Prime.Db.Database+<Inizializza>d__12 - <Inizializza>d__12

I'm a bit confused, as i can't figure out what's the difference between the two situations, therefore i  don't know where to put the hands.
Do you guys have some hints on the case?
It would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

When you say UWP and "a DB somewhere on the PC", then you need either a Standard dll to "read" this "seed" DB, or you include it as content or a resource in your "UWP project".

Have you tried Microsoft.Data.Sqlite? Use a SQLite database in a UWP app

DB is saved in local state folder, uwp is allowed to manage the local state folder and i'm not getting a permission issue. I have tried Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, issue here is that the lib tries to include a e_sqlite.dll file twice rising a compilation error

$"Data Source={ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path}\{DB_NAME}" Maybe you need to check if this string is the correct path in release mode.

IN System.Data.SQLite vesion 1.0.119.0 (which has not be released yet) there is a point which states Avoid NullReferenceException from Path.Combine method when the PublishSingleFile property is enabled for a project.. A case has been opened at the following link https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/375704cf15

Oke,
this is a System.Data.SQLite version 1.0.118.0 (last stable build) issue.
At https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki you can find, right below the Version History section, the newer 1.0.119.0 release notes. At point number 4 is reported the following sentence

Avoid NullReferenceException from Path.Combine method when the PublishSingleFile property is enabled for a project. Pursuant to forum post 66a0d2716a

In the linked forum post more detail can be found. If you're facing the same issue you can give a quick read to the posts to see the available workarounds, i decided to downgrade to version 1.0.117.0 and everything works as expected.
That's all.
